# Getting 403 Forbidden on user_timeline but not on any other API

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, twitter-oauth

Using API auth

```
  var oauth2 = new OAuth2('Consumer Key', 'Consumer Secret', 'https://api.twitter.com/', null, 'oauth2/token', null);
  oauth2.getOAuthAccessToken('', 'grant_type': 'client_credentials' }, function (e, access_token) {

      console.log(access_token); //string that we can use to authenticate request

      requestURL = {
          url: 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline?user_id=' + userid,
          headers: {
              Authorization: 'Bearer ' + access_token
          }
      };




request(URL, function(error, response, body){ 
    console.log(request); 
    console.log(body); }
```

With this code I am getting 403 Forbidden but with the same code on other APIs e.g search/tweets it works fine.
What am I missing here ?
And no, the user is not private.

Answer (score 3):

You have got an error on the called URL. It should be:

```
...
url: 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?user_id=' + userid,
...
```

Comment: just add a .json?

Comment: Exactly,it will then call a JSON service.